# can I use time machine to restore old icloud confirguration?

Tags: icloud

by  mistake, i accidentally blocked my I cloud account.password, security codes, lost the lot.

Is it possible to use the time machine to come back a few days ago when my passwords were still working?

Comment: "blocked" in what way?

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful.  iCloud is locked on the server side, a TM restore would only restore your client side configuration.